# YUM groupinstall behaving strangely for offline repo

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, yum

I've created an offline repository for RHEL 6.2. I put a bunch of packages in a group called JARSS. I made a file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` called `jarss-amg-3.0.repo`. Here it is:

```
[jarss-amg-3.0]
name=<<omitted>>
baseurl=file:///usr/local/install/rpmbuild/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

I performed a `yum clean all` to put this in the metadata. Now, here comes the strange part. I can individually install packages with the command `yum install package`, but `yum groupinstall group` doesn't work.

I get the following error:

```
Error Downloading Packages:
  package error [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because it should be on the local disk. Is this a bug in the `yum` software? I find it hard to believe that it can install individual packages from the disk but not a group.

---

**EDIT**

Here is my `comps.xml` file:

```
<comps>
<group>
    <id>JARSS</id>
    <name>JARSS</name>
    <default>true</default>
    <description>Default 3rd Party Software needed for JARSS installation</description>
    <uservisible>true</uservisible>
    <packagelist>
        <packagereq type="default">ace-tao-amg</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">opendds-amg</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">imlib2</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">imlib2-devel</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">lct</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">xerces-c</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">xerces-c-devel</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">xmlrpc-c</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">xsd</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">atlas</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">atlas-devel</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">blas</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">blas-devel</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">cppunit</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">cppunit-devel</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">lapack</packagereq>
        <packagereq type="default">lapack-devel</packagereq>
    </packagelist>
</group>
</comps>
```

And here is the `ls` command in the local directory:

```
atlas-3.8.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
atlas-devel-3.8.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
blas-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
cmake-2.8.7-1.el6.rfb.x86_64.rpm
comps.xml
cppunit-1.12.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
cppunit-devel-1.12.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
createrepo-0.4.10-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
curl-7.19.7-26.el6.x86_64.rpm
expat-2.0.1-9.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
fltk-1.1.7-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
fltk-devel-1.1.7-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
fox-1.6.33-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
fox-devel-1.6.33-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
ftgl-2.1.3-0.3.rc5.el5.x86_64.rpm
ftgl-devel-2.1.3-0.3.rc5.el5.x86_64.rpm
giblib-1.2.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
giblib-devel-1.2.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
giblib-devel-1.2.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
graphviz-2.28.0-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
imlib2-1.4.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
imlib2-devel-1.4.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
jdk-7u5-linux-x64.rpm
lapack-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
lapack-devel-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
opendds-amg-3.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
plib-1.8.4-8.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm
plib-devel-1.8.4-8.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm
README
remove-native-display-driver-amg-3.0-1.x86_64.rpm
repodata
rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
useradd-amg-3.0-1.x86_64.rpm
wxGTK-2.8.9-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
wxGTK-devel-2.8.9-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
xerces-c-2.7.0-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
xerces-c-devel-2.7.0-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
xmlrpc-c-1.06.18-1.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm
xsd-3.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

---

**EDIT 2**

The `createrepo` command: `createrepo -g comps.xml .`

Comment: Can you show the group XML file you used? The `createrepo` command line used to generate the repo? (If you don't know what I am asking, you didn't do it right and I just gave you some great starts for searching...)

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I edited the original question for you.

Comment: The `createrepo` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

Some of my RPMs in my repository were checked into subversion. Some were not, like the large ones.

Since I didn't want to create a repo with svn metadata inside of it, I did an `svn export` first. Since some of the `rpms` were not in `svn`, they were not copied by the `svn export` command.

When I created the repo, I was attempting to group `rpm`s that were not present, hence the error.